# How to implement a green address in Bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, address, services, trust, green-address

There are a few websites that use [green addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Green_address), but how can one go about implementing it using the standard [Bitcoin API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)?

Answer (score 2):

Green addresses are by convention, not by protocol.  You would need to publish an address and then sign a message with the corresponding private key that says, "I promise never to double-spend any coins from this address."  Then you'd need to convince others to believe your promise.